# Sorry to interrupt This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class JSDemo extends LightningElement {



 firstName;
 lastName;


 

 handleChange(event){
  
   if(this.target.name=='txtFirstName'){
    this.firstName = event.target.value;
   }
   else if(this.target.name=='txtLastName'){
    this.lastName = event.target.value;
   }
   
 }
}
```

```
<template>
 <lightning-card title ="Data Binding" >
  <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
      

      First Name : {firstName}<br/>
      
      Last Name : {lastName}
      
      <lightning-input 
                type="text"
                variant="Standard"
                name="txtFirstName"
                onchange={handleChange}
                label ="Enter the Name">
      </lightning-input>

      <lightning-input 
                 type="text"
                 variant="Standard"
                 name="txtLastName"
                 onchange={handleChange}
                 label ="Enter the Name">
      </lightning-input> 
  </div>              
 </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

this is my lwc component.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to include more information such as any errors related to your component visible in the browser console. Also, how is this component included in the page (is it exposed and added via Lightning App Builder? Adding the meta.xml file will help us understand this too)? What sort of page is it? A code dump like this with little to no context makes for a poor question and could end up not getting answered.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because of the `this` keyword you have used in the if condition. Instead of the `this` keyword you need to use `event`. Because you have to get the field name of the input which is changed.

Below is the updated code:

HTML:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Data Binding">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        First Name : {firstName}<br/>
        Last Name : {lastName}

        <lightning-input type="text" variant="Standard" name="txtFirstName" onchange={handleChange}
            label="Enter the Name">
        </lightning-input>

        <lightning-input type="text" variant="Standard" name="txtLastName" onchange={handleChange}
            label="Enter the Name">
        </lightning-input>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc'; 

export default class DataBinding extends LightningElement {
    firstName;
    lastName;
    handleChange(event) {

        if (event.target.name == 'txtFirstName') {
            this.firstName = event.target.value;
        }
        else if (event.target.name == 'txtLastName') {
            this.lastName = event.target.value;
        }

    }
}
```